# Materialize sidebar

Tags: material-design, materialize

I am making a small demo in angular but firstly i am working on my design part.
I am using Materialize CSS.
Here is my code :

```
    <nav class="blue z-depth-1">      
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
              <a  class="brand-logo " (click)="toggleSideBar()">
                   <i class="material-icons">menu</i> Demo
              </a>                 
        </div>
      </nav>
     <ul  id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed z-depth-1 collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">


       <li class="bold">
        <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">

              <li class="bold">
                    <a class="collapsible-header  waves-effect waves-default">
                         <i class="material-icons prefix">dashboard</i>Dashboard</a>

              </li>
              <li class="bold">
                    <a class="collapsible-header  waves-effect waves-default">
                          <i class="material-icons">face</i>Employee Master
                    </a>
                    <div class="collapsible-body">
                    <ul>
                          <li><a href="badges.html">test</a></li>
                          <li><a href="buttons.html">test</a></li>
                          <li><a href="breadcrumbs.html">test</a></li>

                    </ul>
                   </div>
              </li>

      </ul>
      </li>
```

Here is the issue i am facing please refer my image
[Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PujTa.png)

Comment: make a demo of above code on codepen and i will help you out with solution.

Comment: I have made a small demo, please check it  here   http://codepen.io/ashwani44/pen/oWQxNN    . The problem is i am making demo using angular 2 with Materialize and on code pen while making a demo i am getting different layout of my sidebar.   I wish to achieve sidebar something like i found here if you can just guide me the design of sidebar and  menus i found in this link  : http://byrushan.com/projects/ma/1-5-1/jquery/

Answer (score 1):

First of all thank you for posting codepen. I have gone through your work and made my own demo of sidebar nav which works the way you want.

The list of things i changed are shown below.

1. The latest materialize css and js version `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css` and `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js`
2. Added a bunch of css to make it look like you shown in the reference link

   `// The overall padding of <a> tag changed
   .side-nav li>a{ padding: 0 15px; }`

   `// The padding between icon and text changed
   .side-nav li>a>i, .side-nav li>a>[class^="mdi-"], .side-nav li>a li>a>[class*="mdi-"], .side-nav li>a>i.material-icons{ margin: 0 15px 0 0; }`

   `// Alignment of collapsible list
   .side-nav .collapsible-body{ padding: 0 30px; }`

**The HTML code is provided, along with working demo in the codepen link below:**

```
`http://codepen.io/nirajtech/pen/bWQMRE`
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This is helpful but when i am hovering collapsible body then on mouse over its covering only the padding area . How can i make the whole area as a clickable ? Like in our example the last collapsible header DropDown with options First second Third Fourth